# Как склонировать проект на Strapi сохранив данные

Tags: reactjs, graphql, gatsbyjs, strapi

Всем привет. Столкнулся с такой проблемой. Создал проект на стэке Strapi + Gatsby (под windows). Добавил администратора при первичной инициализации Strapi. Создал несколько страниц, компонентов и тд. В Strapi Cms создал несколько типов контента, а также добавил некоторое количество  записей.
Далее запушил всё это на GitHub. Теперь пытаюсь склонировать и запустить этот проект на другом компе (Mac OS). После команды strapi develop страница localhost:1337/admin/auth/login редиректит на localhost:1337/admin/register, предлагая создать нового админа (под созданным ранее залогиниться не могу).
Ок, создаю новую учётную запись в Strapi cms, но обнаруживается, что пропали все внесённые данные, причём сами типы контента есть, а записей нет, а также в списке администраторов только один вновь созданный.
Вопрос: как правильно запушить, а потом склонировать проект, чтобы все данные сохранились, и была полная копия проекта, но на другом компе?

Comment: Встречный вопрос: база данных запушилась на GitHub?
Когда-то пробовал клонировать Strapi, но пока не останавливал его на сервере - БД не копировалась.

Comment: База данных, как я понимаю, находится в .tmp/data.db. По умолчанию эта папка игнорится в .gitignore. В итоге запушил вместе с этой папкой. Авторизуюсь под админом, всё ок, но теперь вместо панели управления cms белый экран, а в консоли куча ошибок (An error has occured... TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined... и т.д.).

Comment: Через Git не клонировал, тут мне затруднительно советовать.
Папки "\components\content" и "node_modules" перенесены полностью?